# How to choose what to be written to the back-end with Celery?

Tags: python, celery

I am using Celery for a web-scraping project I have. And sometimes the URLs in the queue will be duplicates. That is why the task function returns None if it has seen this URL.
How to stop **Celery** from writing a result to the result backend if the value is None or any other value that I don't like?

Comment: Does anything stop you from simply returning None in that case?

Comment: I do return None, but the task id and information are still written to the database backend and i don't want that.

Comment: Perhaps marking the task with `ignore_result` could make Celery store nothing in the result backend. Worth a try.